# Selenium Click Text [JAVA]

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
List<WebElement> giftNum = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[text()='Gift']"));
            int lastElementGift = giftNum.size();
            System.out.println("There are " + lastElementGift + " # of Gift texts in the page.");
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
// The line below is where I have the issue of the text not being clicked
            giftNum.get(lastElementGift - 1).click();
```

No errors are present when doing this, but I'm trying to click a specific text on a page.

Comment: It does show how many texts with "Gift" are present on the page though

Comment: Can you post with error logs? Your codes seems fine.

Comment: @Alienboy This code is fine. Is the item, which you are trying to click is clickable? You can check the item in page. See, what it does, when you click on it? If you can share the URL, quick help can be given

Comment: please add screenshot and log trace for this. that would be more helpful